# How do you add strict tier pricing?

Tags: tierprice, tiered-pricing, magento1.9.2.4

I have an issue where I need to have strict tiered pricing.

Right now you can order based on tier like...

Order 250 and above pay 1.77

Order 500 and above pay 1.64

Order 1000 and above pay 1.54

but what i need is more like...

Order 250 pay 1.77

Order 500 pay 1.64

Order 1000 pay 1.54

And you cant order any increments in between.

I have a ton of products like this so I am hoping not to have to convert them to configurable products (if thats possible) to make this work. If you know a working extension for 1.9.2.4 that would work too. Could possibly pay but only if necessary.

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to check this extension link : https://www.magecomp.com/magento-tier-price.html

It work according to your requirement. You can check demo so you get idea. You just display tier price as dropdown so no other option avilabel for qty and user must need to purchase specific qty.

Answer (score 0):

This is documented here fortunately - http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-price-tier.html

There are extensions probably but I think you can do this in native Magento 1.